# Saving image to a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In this page I have an image and a submit button. When the submit button is clicked, the image should be saved to the database, but it's not working.

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

     <div id="pic"></div>
     <img src="abc.jpg">
     </div>
     <div id="button">
     <input type="submit" value ="go"></input>
     </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**script.js**

This script gets the image from scr and saves to the database through save.php page.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#button').submit(function(event) { //when click on the go button
        var base64image = $('#pic').attr('src'); //getting image from the scr

        $.post( 
            "save.php", //processing php page

            {
                image: base64image
            },

            function(data) {
                $('.l_m_pic').html(data); //submit data 
            }
        );

        return false;
    });
});
```

**save.php**

This PHP page saves the image to the database.

```
<?php

$img = $_REQUEST['image']; //getting image through jquery
$db_host = "localhost";    //host
$db_user = "user";         //user name
$db_password = "1234";     //password
$db_name = "abc"; 

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$dbc = mssql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password); 

if ($dbc == FALSE) die ("Error."); 

mssql_select_db($db_name, $dbc) or die ("Error."); 

$query_pic = " INSERT INTO pictable (picname)VALUES (0x".$img['hex'].")";

//insert image to the database
if (mssql_query($query_pic,$dbc)) {
    echo "success"; //print succes
} else {
    echo"error";    //print error
}

?>
```

Comment: highly recommended not to put the image in the db, store it in the file system and its name\path in the db

Comment: @dagon why not to put image in the database?

Comment: It would help if you wrote what javascript/php/mysql errors you are getting

Comment: bcz writing image bytes to db is costly operation and avoided by most.

Comment: Is this selector correct `$('.#pic').attr('src');`? **.#** or just **#**?

Comment: <input> does not require a enclosing. your </div> is enclosed without opened div

Comment: I dont think its mssql and its mysql and also it must be mysqli in the newer version

Comment: To echo what @Dagon is saying: the usual practice is to upload a file to the **server**, and then link to it in the database. You'd be storing a huge amount of information in the form of a `blob` in your database.

Comment: @niko, I thought that too at first, but check out this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php. Turns out there is a MS SQL PHP API.

Comment: (Also in respond to @Dragon)  If you store the image in the filesystem, you have much more and easier caching methods available. You may also distribute the image through a cookie-less, static domain or a CDN. You just can't do that if you put the image data into the DBMS, because you can't mount database tables to somewhere. You are limiting your further options for no reason.

Comment: Several errors I want to point out in your code: unopened `</div>`, missing space between `echo` and `"error"`, `$('.#pic')` should be `$('#pic')`, and there is no `$('.l_m_pic')` element in your HTML.

Comment: Even if your selector wasn’t nonsense – expecting to be able to read the base64-encoded image data out of the `src` attribute of an image, if this was not _set_ as a Data URI before certainly is … voting to close as “too broad”, because you obviously just cobbled that together replacing actual research on the topic by wishful thinking.

Comment: @Spikolynn its showing the error "
Notice: Undefined index: image in save.php"

Comment: Thank you @JoshBeam for letting me know a new thing today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem I see is `var base64image = $('.#pic').attr('src');` :

Even if the jQuery selector here is correct (should be '#pic img' I think) you would only get the image link. This would fix the current error but it would not be what you want because it is not in base64 yet.

next problem will probably be with `$img['hex']` which should be replaced with just $img once you have the image data in correct format.

That said, I agree that you should seldom have reason to store images in database.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: I think you should save the image to disk and write only file names in the database. Or perhaps skip database altogether if it would still work.

Comment: but then how to get the image src in the jquery variable?

Comment: oh, I see. you have an extra </div> in <div id="pic"></div>

This was all mentioned in the comments fyi